# WebStorm - How to keep LiveTemplates in a repository?

Tags: javascript, git, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm looking for a solution that allows the rest of my team to work with my custom Webstorm-LiveTemplates.

Is there a way to keep live templates in a repository like git?
I need that WebStorm automatically loads it...

Answer (score 0):

If you have NPM (Node Package Manager) installed you can use:

[live-template-installer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-template-installer)

> Command line utility for automatically installing live templates to
> Intellij or Webstorm

One of the features is installing a live template from git repo.

> It is intended to sync to a git for easy distribution and backup of
> templates.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a solution like [.editorconfig project](http://editorconfig.org/), a simple-way to tell WebStorm which liveTemplates we are using for single project...

I would not be obligated to perform tasks grunt or similar